# problem with creating a wordpress post slider

Tags: posts, jquery, slideshow

firstly i know i have to add some code explaining what i have done before.

But honestly i had tried more than ten tutorial concerning wordpress post slider based on flexslider or bxslider or other trics with jquery but seriously guys I don't where is the problem, i can't show slider the best thingi show is a list of post image and content vertically.

So my question is how to create a wordpress post slider?

PS. i had some linked jquery , those files could interrupt the slider. post

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you don't know how to use the slider plugins you choose. In fact if you know JavaScript, you could make a simple slider without jQuery.

To create a post slider, the steps is:

1: Create a post list by WordPress function. Use a `<ul>` label to wrap the list and use `<li>` label wrap every post:

```
<div class="sliderContainer">
    <ul class="slider">
        <li class="sliderItem"><article>/* post content */</article></li>
        <li class="sliderItem"><article>/* post content */</article></li>
        <li class="sliderItem"><article>/* post content */</article></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

2: Set the style by CSS as below:

```
.sliderContainer{position:relative;overflow:hidden;}
.slider{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;}
.sliderItem{float:left;line-height:0;font-size:0;*zoom:1;}
.sliderItem:after{display:table;content:'';clear:both;}
```

Also you should set the `width` and `height` of the container. Now you should get a horizontal post list and only the first post be shown(the others is overflow and is hidden).

3: Now use JavaScript to move the `.slider` which is the `<ul>` label. The principle is see the `<ul>` as a belt and move it `width` distance once a time.

If you don't need to consider IE9- then use the CSS3's `transition` and `transform:translateX` to make the animation. Use JavaScript to add or remove the `transition` and `transform` style.

You still need to do some detail work to make the JavsScript part more practical but this is a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer, yes i don't have a good level in javascript but i have created the same thing that you said and its worked but its need the animation so i tried to be based on flex slider but without any success thats my code, i know that this code is for attachement but i don't have anything shown.

```
function revconcept_get_images($post_id) {
global $post;

 $thumbnail_ID = get_post_thumbnail_id();

 $images = get_children( array('post_parent' => $post_id, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'menu_order ID') );

 if ($images) :

     foreach ($images as $attachment_id => $image) :

         $img_alt = get_post_meta($attachment_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true); //alt
         if ($img_alt == '') : $img_alt = $image->post_title; endif;

         $big_array = image_downsize( $image->ID, 'large' );
         $img_url = $big_array[0];

         echo '<li>';
         echo '<img src="';
         echo $img_url;
         echo '" alt="';
         echo $img_alt;
         echo '" />';
         echo '</li><!--end slide-->';

 endforeach; endif; }
```

i added this function in function.php and this one in header

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/flexslider.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
```

and then i display the attachement in single.php by this one.

```
<div class="flexslider">
<ul class="slides">
    <?php revconcept_get_images("$post->ID"); ?>
</ul>
```